# EasyNetQ rabbitMq update version Json error

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I was using EasyNetQ v0.27.1.216 with Newtonsoft.Json v4.5.11 and RabbitMq.Client v3.2.1 
I update, to solve an issue of connection, now i have EasyNetQ v0.33.1.276, Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.3 and RabbitMq.Client v3.3.2

Before everything was fine but since the update I got error when i try to publish some object.

> "Exception":"System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>   ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error resolving type specified in JSON
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[[Object1,
>   Object2],[Object3, Object4]], Object5],[Object3, Object6]], Object5'.
>   Path 'Object3.$type', line 1, position 464. --->
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not find type...

And it continue like that for 3 pages of word.
I can post it all but i have to change all the names...

Not sure what to do with that...

Comment: What do you get when you use `TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.None` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but same error. I try TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None then PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None, TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found need to use List element and not IEnumerable (IEnumerable worked before). All work with .ToList()